# Passing test variables to test using Citrus Framework

Tags: java, jaxb, citrus-framework

I am considering Citrus Framework to automate some XML API test cases.

One success factor will be the ability to pass metadata as test variables. In other words, instead of:

```
<loginId>12345</loginID>
   <password>mypassword</password>
```

...we have:

```
<LoginInfo LoginId="12345" LoginPassword="password"/>
```

is it possible to pass data that does not exist between 2 nodes, as follows?:

```
  <LoginInfo LoginId=${loginId} LoginPassword="password"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
<LoginInfo LoginId="${loginId}" LoginPassword="password"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Christoph - I will try